# pthread_cond_init if initialized statically, should it be destroyed before using it again

Tags: pthreads

If pthread_cond_init is statically initialized as below, pthread_cond_t cond =  PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; then when the pthread_cond_signal(&cond) is issued , should the cond variable be destroyed before waiting on the condition again ?

I referred below it does not explain this case.
http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_init

Edited After following up with comments:

```
    pthread_mutex_t mutex=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t  cond=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int functionA (int a)
    {
        while ( a> 10)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
            a =15;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            //pthread_cond_destroy(&cond); --- destroy after signalling
            usleep(1000);
        }
    }

    int functionB (int a)
    {
      while ( a > 10)
      {
        //pthread_attr_init( &attr );
       //  pthread_cond_init(&cond, &attr); --- if cond is destryoed
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond);
        printf(" condition is unblocked <%d>",a);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        usleep(1000);
      }
    }

    int main (void)
    {
        int a =5;   

        pthread_attr_init( &attr );
        pthread_create( NULL, &attr, functionB, NULL);
        pthread_create( NULL, &attr, functionA, NULL);
        while (1);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean *after* `pthread_cond_signal(&cond)`?

Comment: yes after pthread_cond_signal(&cond) and unlocking the mutex .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the conditional variable was statically initialized (`PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER`), then you don't need to destroy it.
Although there's no direct reference whether destroying a statically allocated conditional variable using `pthread_cond_wait()`, we can from:

> In cases where default condition variable attributes are appropriate,
>   the macro PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER can be used to initialize condition
>   variables. The effect shall be equivalent to dynamic initialization by
>   a call to pthread_cond_init() with parameter attr specified as NULL,
>   except that no error checks are performed.

that it's allowed. So destroying is fine as long as no other threads are waiting on the same condition (or will do so later in the program).

If you intend to reuse the conditional variable after destroying it, then it must be reinitialized again, which is allowed by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_destroy.html):

> A destroyed condition variable object can be reinitialized using
>   pthread_cond_init(); the results of otherwise referencing the object
>   after it has been destroyed are undefined.

Comment: I don't believe the citation you give amounts to a prohibition against `pthread_cond_destroy()`ing a statically initialized condition.

Comment: [This](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_destroy.3p.html) *strongly* implies that you *do* need to destroy a statically init'ed condition before re-init'ing it: *In cases where default condition variable attributes are appropriate,
       the macro PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER can be used to initialize
       condition variables. The effect shall be **equivalent to** dynamic
       initialization by a call to pthread_cond_init() with parameter attr
       specified as NULL, except that no error checks are performed.* (emphasis mine). Not opengroup though...

Comment: I didn't to intend imply so. Fixed the wording. To the question of "whether it's OK to do" -- I can't find any direct reference. Butenhof's book I have says "don't need to" but that doesn't refute if doing so is not allowed. I'll dig deeper to see if I can find any references in POSIX.

Comment: Well, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_destroy.html) doesn't explicitly distinguish between statically and dynamically init'ed conditions as arguments to `pthread_cond_destroy()`, and it *requires* that a condition be destroyed before it can be reinit'ed. So far, I'd say that looks an awful lot like "Yes, you *do* (technically) need to destroy the condition".

Comment: The wording you quoted is the same in POSIX too. But, to my reading, it implies that the two ways of initializing are the equivalent and I am not sure if everything else follows.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that on the opengroup site. Well, "equivalent" is pretty unambiguous.

Comment: @EOF After looking at glibc (on the assumption that nptl is implemented per POSIX), I came to the conclusion that your interpretation is correct and fixed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @P.P  -- I have updated the reference code.  So even if  the cond is to be used by the same threads of the process,  every signaling should  destroy it and every wait should re-initialize it.  Is this correct ?

Comment: @Just You don't need destroy it at all in your reference code. The two threads communicate with each other using `cond` and there's no need to reinitialize it everytime. In fact, doing so will lead to a race between two threads for initializing `cond`. So, a big no.

Comment: Your answer is a bit misleading when you say *"If you intend to reuse the conditional variable then it must be destroyed and reinitialize again..."* - reusing the condition variable (by continuing to wait on it and signal it) does not require destroying and reinitialising it - you only need to reinitialise if you want to change the condition variable attributes, which is highly unlikely.